# How to align wrapper of CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dropdown menu, and got it looking pretty much how I want, but the way I have achieved the layout makes hover area a bit too large on the right hand side, illustrated here by the grey box. I want hovering over the grey box (the .dropdown element) to be treated as the white area and dismiss the dropdown.

How can I get the menu to dismiss when hovering over the grey .dropdown area?

working demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMarBb?editors=1100

[image]

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: silver;
}

li:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: none;
}

.wrapper {
  /*   background: green; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -50%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.inner {
  background: darkorange;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 45px 0 rgba(12, 0, 51, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.inner:before,
.inner:after,
.inner li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  border: 12px outset transparent;
  margin-top: 29px;
}

.inner:after {
  border-bottom: 12px solid darkorange;
  top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-C</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is it okay to use other than <li> inside <ul> ???

Comment: @Chiller no, it's not ok and it should be corrected. it's invalid

Comment: That's a great point. Billy, I'd move your style elements inside the list items (and use pseudo-elements instead where you can).

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's what i thought... maybe he should use `<section><section><ul><li>...` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you want the dropdown to hide when you stop hovering over the orange section.

What I've done to your code below is `position:absolute` the elements with `left:50%` and `transform:translate(-50%)`. This will centre-align the elements horizontally in such a way that the orange links will be over the gray area.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background: silver;
}

li:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: none;
}

.wrapper {
  /*   background: green; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.inner {
  background: darkorange;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 45px 0 rgba(12, 0, 51, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.inner:before,
.inner:after,
.inner li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 12px outset transparent;
  margin-top: 29px;
}

.inner:after {
  border-bottom: 12px solid darkorange;
  top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-C</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the inline comments on the CSS for how I'm controlling hover events for specific elements. This approach leaves the gray area directly above the dropdown active, which I think is a good behavior.

Note: This may not work in Safari. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: silver;
  pointer-events: none; /* <-- disable hover events */
}

li:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: none;
}

.wrapper {
  /*   background: green; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -50%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  pointer-events: all; /* <-- enable hover events */
}

.inner {
  background: darkorange;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 45px 0 rgba(12, 0, 51, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.inner:before,
.inner:after,
.inner li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  border: 12px outset transparent;
  margin-top: 29px;
}

.inner:after {
  border-bottom: 12px solid darkorange;
  top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-C</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem is to remove `margin-left` on `.dropdown` and `.wrapper`, and then center the arrow with :

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Since there is also a `margin-top` on this element you can write `margin: 29px auto 0;` instead of `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: silver;
}

li:hover .dropdown,
.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: none;
}

.wrapper {
  /*   background: green; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.inner {
  background: darkorange;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 45px 0 rgba(12, 0, 51, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.inner:before,
.inner:after,
.inner li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 12px outset transparent;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 29px auto 0;
}

.inner:after {
  border-bottom: 12px solid darkorange;
  top: -23px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-C</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
          </section>
        </section>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Edit:** as Chiller and Temani Afif said in the comments section, the structure of your code is invalid. I made a quick clean up of your example so you can see what you can do with less wrapped elements.

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a { color: #fff; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

li:hover .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown { padding-top: 30px; }

.dropdown li {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown li:first-child { border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
.dropdown li:last-child { border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; }

.dropdown li:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-color: darkorange;
  border-width: 12px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```